# Create socket for laravel and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sockets

I wrote the backend with Laravel as an api and the front with vueJs, of course, are completely separate.

Now I want to create notifications for some tasks.

I do not want to use the pusher and I want to create the socket myself (to practice and understand how it works).
Now my question is, do I have to create a separate socket for both Back and Front and connect both of them to the same port?

Thankful.

Comment: Laravel framework includes a submodule called `Illuminate\Broadcasting` to implement WebSockets for real-time, live-updating user interfaces. They provide different socket connections using `pusher` and `redis` and so on. I recommend you to read this link; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`laravel-echo`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo) on the client-side and use the [`laravel-echo-server`](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) on the server-side.

at the first, you should install and configure the `laravel-echo-serve` then run it in your server.

now for client-side, install the laravel-echo and listen to your custom port which you defined in `laravel-echo-serve` config.

And for call your socket, just enough create an event in your laravel project and create an instance like below and place it in your desired location:

```php
event(new App/Events/ExampleEvent());
```